# Ruby or ROR - arguments of function separated by '||'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've just encountered an interesting piece of code. I'd like to determine if it's a ruby standard or a rails convention.

```
redirect_to(session[:return_to] || users_path)
```

This prevents redirect_to :back from causing errors in some cases. In c++ something like that would mean a function with one bool argument. But here it seems to work another way - it takes that argument which isn't a nil I suppose. Can someone explain it to me and show an example definition of such a function, which takes arguments separated by '||'?

Bye

Comment: A bit of a tangent, but I feel the `or` operator would be more "correct" in this situation (http://avdi.org/devblog/2010/08/02/using-and-and-or-in-ruby/). Doesn't answer the question but I thought I'd put it out there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boolean operators such as `||` and `&&` return the last evaluated statement.

An example,

`puts "hi" && "no"`

The above will print "no" since both strings are considered 'truthy' and "no" was the last value called.

In this case the programmer is taking advantage of the short circuit nature of the `||` operator. So another example,

`puts "hi" || "no"`

The above will output "hi" since "hi" is considered truthy and or is short circuited "hi" was the last value called from the expression and will be returned.

You will see this kind of construct a lot in ruby, especially with `if`s.

```
a = if true
  "A will be set to this string"
else
  "This will never happen"
end

puts a #=> A will be set to this string
```

Edit: As nick mentioned, it is important to note that only `nil` and `false` are treated as "falsy". Some interesting examples

```
a = nil || "hi"
puts a #=> "hi"
a = false || "hi"
puts a #=> "hi"
```

In these two cases the first argument is "falsy" so the "hi" is evaluated and returned (and then assigned to a)

```
a = Object.new || "hi"
puts a #=> <Object:0x10832420>
```

In this case (and for any other value as the first argument) Object.new is "true" and thus "hi" is never evaluated. In your particular example, the author was most likely testing for the presence (not nil) of `session[:return_to]`. This can be very useful but always remember that it may not work properly if `false` is a valid value.

Comment: We should add that only `nil` and `false` evaluate to false in ruby. This kind of expression is idiomatic for `try_this || fall_back_in_case_the_other_was_nil`.

Comment: Agreed. I've expanded to try and convey this.

Answer (score 3):

This is called [Short-Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) and it is common in many programming languages

In plain English, your statement says

> "redirect to session[:return_to] if it is present, if not, redirect to users_path"

Answer (score 2):

It calls `redirect_to(session[:return_to])` if `session[:return_to]` is truthy (e.g. not `nil` or `false`).

If `session[:return_to]` is falsy, then it calls `redirect_to(users_path)`.

See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Operators#Logical_Or.

Answer (score 1):

The logical OR is short-circuited, meaning that if the left-hand side is "true", or non-nil, then the value of the entire expression is the left-hand side, and the right-hand side is never considered. So if `session[:return_to]` is non-nil, it is the value of the expression. If it is nil, though, then the value of the expression is the value of the right-hand side, i.e. the value of `user_path`.

You can even write things like `x || x = "foo"`, in which case `x` only gets reassigned if it was nil to begin with, but won't be touched if it is non-nil.

As for the function, it just takes a string, and it doesn't care what you plug in to the argument.